# Use variables in send_email()

Tags: python, django, django-email

I use `html` as message in one email and pass some variables like this:

```
subject = 'Some Subject'
plain = render_to_string('templates/email/message.txt',{'name':variableWithSomeValue,'email':otherVariable})
html = render_to_string('templates/email/message.html',{'name':variableWithSomeValue,'email':otherVariable})
from_email = setting.EMAIL_HOST_USER
send_email(subject, plain, from_email, [variableToEmail], fail_silently=False, html_message=html)
```

That works good but now I need to take the message content from one table from the database, the table have three columns, in the first register have this values in each column. Column `subject` have `Account Info`, column `plain` have `Hello {{name}}. Now you can access to the site using this email address {{email}}.` and the column `html` have `<p>Hello <strong>{{name}}</strong>.</p> <p>Now you can access to the site using this email address <strong>email</strong>.</p>`.

So to take the values from the database I do this `obj = ModelTable.objects.get(id=1)` then this:

```
subject = obj.subject
plain = (obj.plain,{'name':variableWithSomeValue,'email':otherVariable})
html = (obj.html,{'name':variableWithSomeValue,'email':otherVariable})
from_email = setting.EMAIL_HOST_USER
send_email(subject, plain, from_email, [variableToEmail], fail_silently=False, html_message=html)
```

But this give me the error

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

so I tried to passing `.encode(´utf-8´)` for the values and gives me the same error, then change the value for each variable and find that the problem comes from `plain = (obj.plain,{'name':variableWithSomeValue,'email':otherVariable})` and `html = (obj.html,{'name':variableWithSomeValue,'email':otherVariable})` so I think that I passing the variables in the wrong way, so **How can I do it in the right way?** or maybe is for the encoding of the database but I think that using `.encode(utf-8)` should solve that problem but I really think that I pass the variables `name` and `email` in the wrong way.

Sorry for the long post and my bad grammar, if need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that obj.plain and obj.html are strings representing your templates (as stored in the database)?

If that is the case, then you still need to render your email content. However, instead of using `render_to_string`, which takes as it's first argument a template path, you will want to create a template based on your string, and then render that template. Consider something like the following:

```
...
from django.template import Context, Template
plain_template = Template(obj.plain)
context = Context({'name':variableWithSomeValue,'email':otherVariable})
email_context = plain_template.render(context)
...
send_email(...)
```

Here's a link that better explains rendering string templates, as opposed to rendering template files.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context